# Are there any minimum-degree-5 triangulations of the sphere for which every four-coloring consists of six Kempe chains, one for each color-pair?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm interested only in triangulations that have no separating triangles (i.e. triangles for which there are vertices both inside and outside the triangle).

The 5-regular icosahedron is one.  Are there any others?

(A question I've asked here before, but more succinctly this time around.)